# Ubuntu 11.04: Banshee doesn't play

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04, banshee

In Ubuntu 11.04, Rhythmbox still works fine but Banshee is silent.

Is anyone else having such a problem, and if so how did you fix it?

Comment: Open up a terminal. Type: banshee  (And share the output with us. http://pastebin.com will be fine if it's a long output.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this problem as well. I came across someone pointing to this bug report:

> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/banshee/+bug/717850

If you have the files `libGL.so.1` and `libGL.so.1.2` located in `/usr/lib`, then removing them might solve the problem, since `libGL.so` doesn't belong in `/usr/lib`.

A possible solution according to the bug report is:

```
rm /usr/lib/libGL.so.1  
rm /usr/lib/libGL.so.1.2
```

In my case these files are not present, so I'm continuing to find a solution.